# Create Spark context from Python in order to run databricks sql

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-sql

I've been following this [tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html) which lets me connect to Databricks from Python and then run delta table queries. However, I've stumbled upon a problem. When I run it for the FIRST time, I get the following error:

> Container container-name in account
> storage-account.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create
> it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in
> the configuration.

When I go back to my Databricks cluster and run this code snippet

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark_context =SparkContext.getOrCreate()

if StorageAccountName is not None and StorageAccountAccessKey is not None:
  print('Configuring the spark context...')
  spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
    f"fs.azure.account.key.{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
    StorageAccountAccessKey)
```

(where `StorageAccountName` and `AccessKey` are known) then run my Python app once again, it runs successfully without throwing the previous error. I'd like to ask, is there a way to run this code snippet from my Python app and at the same time reflect it on my Databricks cluster?

Comment: are you running this code via Databrics Connect, or directly on the cluster?

Comment: The code snippet is directly on the cluster. How could I run it from my PyCharm? @AlexOtt

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add these configuration options to the cluster itself as it's described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api). You need to set following Spark property, the same as you do in your code:

```
fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net <storage-account-access-key>
```

For security, it's better to put access key into secret scope, and refer it from Spark configuration (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#retrieve-a-spark-configuration-property-from-a-secret))

Comment: This should go through `databricks-connect` or just `pyspark`?

Comment: It’s should be done on cluster that you are querying

Comment: directly on databricks? sorry if the question seems kind of dumb, I'm the new guy when it comes to databricks

Comment: Yes, go to your cluster, click Edit, scroll down to "Advanced options", put that configuration into "Spark" part

Comment: Ah, I understand. Just one more question, what if I have a few more clusters. Would I need to configure this on all of them?

Comment: yes. this option provides the way for clusters to authenticate to the storage account. But I would recommend to use SAS key instead of storage key

Comment: Is there a way to connect to Databricks from a Python IDE and then run this `fs.azure.account.key...` from there?

Comment: But why do you need this?

Comment: I'll tell you the use-case I have. So, I have delta tables in Databricks. My team uses Databricks for manipulating data and it creates delta tables from most of them. Now what I need to build is, create an API which will let the user query a delta table. If a user wants to preview the first 100 rows from delta table A, my API should connect to Databricks, run the query SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 100, the API should get the result and give it back to the client app. Now this app that I work on, uses multiple storage accounts on the same cluster I believe. That's why I need this functionality. 1/2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239663/discussion-between-anthino12-and-alex-ott).